# how to set a value way on nested pojo

Tags: java, reflection

Lets say i have an object x with this nested properties:

x.y.z.y
i mean x contains object y that contains z... etc...

and i want to set :
x.y.z.y = 7.0 (in case y is an Double)

but z is null

can you suggest a patten for it?

both ways of:

maybe with reflection (may create predecessor nulls with default values or to ignore the set if one of the predecessors is null?

or better solution?

thanks.

Comment: Optional.ofNullable(x).map(X::getY).map(Y::getZ).ifPresent(z->z.setY(some))

Comment: Maybe `Optional.ofNullable(x).map(x -> x.y).map(y -> y.z).ifPresent(z -> z.y = 7.0)`, or `Optional.ofNullable(x.y.z).ifPresent(z -> z.y = 7.0)` if only `z` can be `null`. Do not use reflection for this though.

Comment: What if `y` or `z` is `List` or an `Optional` ?